# lib-sass breaking harp on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, libsass, node-sass, harp

Interesting problem, Using harp to build a simple app, then deploying it to Heroku, which is proving to be an issue. The last deploy worked flawlessly using the Harp buildpack, But now it's breaking on deploy.

Nothing has changed that should be causing this, no updates to node modules, or node version. the logs and Papertrail are complaining:

```
Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
```

After this, I branched off and tried to check on lib-sass in

```
/app/node_modules/harp/node_modules/terraform/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22
```

As per the logs, tried reinstalling it, but no avail. Anyone ever run into this? could it be a problem with the buildpack?

Answer (score 1):

seems to be an issue with Node 0.12.

https://github.com/zeke/harp-buildpack/issues/12

I was able to get my app running by just not using the buildpack, adding

```
"dependencies": {
    "harp": "~0.12.1"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "0.10.x"
},
```

to `package.json` and adding a `server.js` with

```
require('harp').server(__dirname, { port: process.env.PORT || 9000 })
```